# How to change Grid View using Pjax in yii2?

Tags: php, ajax, gridview, yii2, pjax

Ok, ill explain what i have first,

**--A database table called cases.**

This holds all of the cases to i need to display in a gridview

**--Three tables called Category, Subcategory and ChildCategory**

The cases from table case will be linked to a childcategory.

So i have made three DropDownLists that are populated from the individual category tables in the database. For example:

**_categories.php**

```
 yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'categories']); 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin();

    echo $form->field($searchModel, 'category')
                ->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map($allCategory, 'id', 'name'),
                    [
                        'onchange'=>'getSubcategory()',
                    ]
    );

    //To stop errors, if first category not chosen make subcategory and empty drop down.
    $subcategory = array(
        "empty" => ""

    );

    echo $form->field($searchModel, 'subcategory')
                ->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map($subcategory, 'id', 'name'),
                    [
                       'onchange'=>'getChildcategory()',
                    ]
    );
    //To stop errors, if second category not chosen make childcategory and empty drop down.
    $childcategory = array(
        "empty" => ""
    );
    echo $form->field($searchModel, 'childcategory')
                ->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map($childcategory, 'id', 'name'),
                    [
                       //'onchange'=>'getChildCategory()',
                        'onchange'=>'submitNow()',
                    ]
    );

    ActiveForm::end();
    yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
```

So what happens is when the first category is selected it runs "onchange" => getSubcategory. This will basically send an Ajax request to my controller with the value of the selected option. It will then pull back the subcategories where the subcategory_id = the value of the selected option. It then populated the subcategory drop down with this information.

**this function is on _categories.php with the category drop downlists above**

```
 function getSubcategory(){
        //#casesearch-category is the first drop down list
        var firstcategory = $('#casesearch-category').val();
            var childcategory = document.getElementById('casesearch-childcategory');
            childcategory.options.length = 0;
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('cases/subcategories') ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 
                    firstcategory: firstcategory 
                },
                success: function(data) {      

                    var subcategory = document.getElementById('casesearch-subcategory');
                    //if select is changed again, make the options length 0 so that it gets rid of previous appends.
                    subcategory.options.length = 0;


                    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        subcategory.options[i] = new Option (data[i].name);
                        subcategory.options[i].value = data[i].subcategory_id;
                    }
                    subcategory.options.selectedIndex = -1;

                   if(subcategory.options.length === 1){
                        getChildcategory();
                    }     
                }
            });
    }
```

So when this ajax request reaches my controller it does this:

**CasesController.php**

```
public function actionSubcategories()
{
   if(isset($_POST['firstcategory'])){
        $firstcategory = $_POST['firstcategory'];
        // SELECT * FROM `subcategory` WHERE `parent_id` = $firstcategory
        $subcategory = Subcategory::findSubcategory($firstcategory);

    }

    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($subcategory);
}
```

Okay so that was just a little bit to help you understand the category side of things. Now i have a gridview that is populated from the database when the page is submitted. However as i have done ajax to get my categories i need the gridview to change with pjax when ever the categories are changed.

So in my controller actionIndex is sends through the searchModel and dataprovider for the gridview like so:

**CasesController.php**

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $model = new Cases;
    $searchModel = new CaseSearch();  
    $allCategory = Category::find()->all();

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'allCategory' => $allCategory,
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

**Then on my index page where it displays the grid view is here::**

NOTE::Index.php renders the category dropdownlists seen above _categories.php

```
 <?= $this->render('_categories', [
    'model' => $model,
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'allCategory' => $allCategory
]) ?>

<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'cases']) ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'case_id',
        'name',
        'judgement_date',
        'year',
        'neutral_citation',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

Ok So here is the part where i am stuck! I assume what i am meant to do is somehow update the searchModel and dataProvider for the gridview but i am unsure how to do this. As if i send an ajax request to controller to change it it will then have to render the page again which defeats the objective.

**at the top of _categories.php**

```
function submitNow(){
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#cases"});  //Reload GridView     
   }
```

This function is called when the last childcategory is selected.I know something will have to happen here to do this but i do not know what. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php use yii\widgets\Pjax; ?>



<?php Pjax::begin() ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'case_id',
        'name',
        'judgement_date',
        'year',
        'neutral_citation',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

Comment: Please add in some explanation to your answer so future readers can easily understand your solution.